# The problem with deletions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

I saw lots of bot answers deletions and it's good that mods clean this GPT stipidity from site. But there are drawbacks as well. Pretty often some useful answers are deleted with comments etc. So mods kinds throw out the baby with the bath water.

Maybe there is a way to block the spammers or delete what they post more selectively, without deleting useful interaction and actual content?

Answer (score 4):

We do not need nor want your spam.

Those answers are, without exception, posted in a violation of our Terms of Service and their usefulness is questionable without proper references and including half-truths as they are.

And yes, I know it's you asking about your own GPT spam being deleted.